# create a list in python only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: python-3.x, list

I originally had a script where I created an empty list in a for loop.
Subsequently, everytime it went through the list, it overwrote the list with an empty list.
I'm not sure it pythonically makes sense to have the list created IN the for loop, but let's say I wanted to...

How can I only create the list if it does not already exist?

I tried the following:

```
if len(field_plane_names) == 0:
    print("list does not exist, creating list")
    field_plane_names = list()
else:
    print("list already exists, only append")
if len(field_plane_dirs) == 0:
    print("list does not exist, creating list")
    field_plane_dirs = list()
else:
    print("list already exists, only append")

if not 'field_plane_names' in globals() or locals():
    field_plane_names = []
    print("list reset")
if not 'field_plane_dirs' in globals() or locals():
    field_plane_dirs = []

if not hasattr(list, 'field_plane_names'):
    field_plane_names = []
    print(plane)
if not hasattr(list, 'field_plane_dirs'):
    field_plane_dirs = []
```

Comment: Pls check whether my answer satisfies ur requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```py
try:
    len(field_plane_names) # Tries to find the length of the list, throws NameError if list does not exist
    print("list already exists, only append")

except NameError:
    print("list does not exist, creating list")
    field_plane_names = list()
```

Comment: If my ans has helped u, pls accept it as the best ans. Thx!